# called the defined function: I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python, astropy, fits

I defined a function to fix and open the fits file in a list. Then call it twice to overly the fits picture. But when I used the parameters of called the function to plot, it shows that the I/O  operation on closed file: "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file". I don't know why it happens. Thank you so much.

The following is the code of defined function

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import applpy
from astropy.io import fits
from astropy.wcs import WCS
from astropy.wcs import FITSFixedWarning
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=FITSFixedWarning)


#### define the function to fix the fitsheader and get the head info.
def fix_fitshead(filelis):
    with fits.open(filelis.replace('\n', ''), mode="readonly") as hdu:
        da = hdu[0].data[:,:]
        he = hdu[0].header
            
    if he["NAXIS"] ==4:
        he["NAXIS"] =2
        for k in ["NAXIS3", "NAXIS4", 
                  "CTYPE3", "CRVAL3", "CDELT3", "CROTA3", "CRPIX3", 
                  "CTYPE4", "CRVAL4", "CDELT4", "CROTA4", "CRPIX4" ]:
            if k in list(he.keys()):
                he.remove(k)
        hdu = fits.PrimaryHDU(da, he)
        print('WCS=',WCS(he))
    elif he["NAXIS"] ==3:
        he["NAXIS"] =1 
        for k in ["NAXIS3","CTYPE3", "CRVAL3", "CRPIX3","CUNIT3", "LBOUND3"]: 
            if k in list(he.keys()):
                he.remove(k)
            if "CDELT3" in h3:
                k1 = "CDELT3"
            elif "CD3_3" in h3:
                k1 = "CD3_3"
                he.remove(k1)
        hdu = fits.PrimaryHDU(da, he)
    else:
        hdu = hdu[0]
    maxvalue = np.nanmax(da)
     
    c = WCS(he).wcs_pix2world([[he["NAXIS1"]/2,he["NAXIS2"]/2]], 1)
    coord = SkyCoord(ra=c[0][0]*u.deg, dec=c[0][1]*u.deg)
    
    if "LINE" in he:
        spec = he["LINE"]
    elif 'MOLECULE' in he:
        spec = he['MOLECULE']
    elif "INSTRUME"in he:
        spec = he['INSTRUME']
        print(he["OBJECT"]) 
#        print(maxvalue) 
        
#    PRODID  = 'reduced-850um'   
    return maxvalue, spec, da, he, hdu, coord


##The following code is plot the overlay picture by calling the defined function.

file_gray = '/Users/hjma/Desktop/smoothdata/progress/13co_fits.list'
file_cont  = '/Users/hjma/Desktop/smoothdata/progress/hcn10_fits.list'

with open(file_gray,'r') as f_gray:
    gray_list = [row_gray.rstrip('\n') for row_gray in f_gray]
with open(file_cont,'r') as f_cont:
    cont_list = [row_cont.rstrip('\n') for row_cont in f_cont]

for filegray in gray_list:
#    print('filegray=',filegray)
    
    #call the defined function
    maxvalue1, spec1, d1, he1, hdu_gray, coord1 = fix_fitshead(filegray)

    for filecont in cont_list:
#        print('filecont=', filecont)

        #call the defined function       
        maxvalue2, spec2, d2, he2, hdu_cont, coord2 = fix_fitshead(filecont)
        print('d2=',d2)
        
        
        fig = plt.figure()
        fig.set_figwidth(4); fig.set_figheight(4)
            
        ff = aplpy.FITSFigure(hdu_gray, figure=fig)
        ff.show_colorscale(cmap="Blues")
        ff.show_contour(hdu_cont, colors="red")
        
        plt.plot([0], label="HCN 1-0", color="r")
        plt.legend()
        plt.tight_layout()
        
        plt.close()
        break`
```

I got the error:

---> 26         ff = aplpy.FITSFigure(hdu_gray, figure=fig)
....
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Comment: `aplpy` isn't defined anywhere. Is this a typo for `applpy`?

Comment: Sorry, It's a typo. It should be "import aplpy"

Comment: Thank you all. The question has been resolved by moving  hdu = fits.PrimaryHDU(da, he) out of the loop.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do in  the `fix_fitshead` function?  It appears to me you're trying to take some 3D or 4D HDUs and reduce them to two dimensions.  But the code you've written doesn't actually achieve that.  First of all, the line `da = hdu[0].data[:,:]` doesn't really do anything.  It just returns the same array.  If you want to drop dimensions you need to specify which 2-D slice of the array you want...

Comment: Then when you do `hdu = fits.PrimaryHDU(da, he)`, the previous work you did of manipulating the `NAXIS` keywords is lost.  See for yourself (insert something after this line like `print(hdu.header)`.  When you pass an array to one of the HDU constructors, no matter what header you pass in it will still update the `NAXIS` keywords to correctly reflect the shape of the data (it is true the base code doesn't understand WCS keywords like `CTYPE3` so those you do need to delete if you want to reduce the dimensions of an HDU).

Comment: Minor note, but you can replace lines like `if k in list(he.keys())` with just `if k in he`.

Answer (score 0):

I added some general comments above on problems with your code you might want to resolve.  I would give you a suggested re-write of your code, except I'm not 100% sure what it's meant to accomplish.  It appears that, among other things, you want it to take 2D slices of 3D or 4D arrays, but as I noted above it doesn't actually achieve that goal.

Anyways, the reason for your error is specifically in the case where the data is already 2D, in your if/elif/else statement you have:

```py
    if he["NAXIS"] == 4:
        ...
        hdu = fits.PrimaryHDU(da, he)
        print('WCS=',WCS(he))
    elif he["NAXIS"] == 3:
        ...
        hdu = fits.PrimaryHDU(da, he)
    else:
        hdu = hdu[0]
```

In the first two cases you read the data from the file before closing the file (`da = hdu[0].data[:,:]`) and created a new HDU object from it.  However, in the last case, you didn't do this and just pass the original HDU object from the closed file (`hdu = hdu[0]`).  Since the file this is from is closed, the data in this HDU can't be ready any longer so you get "I/O operation on closed file" when you pass it to `aplpy.FITSFigure` and it tries to read the HDU data.

One way you could work around this is change that last line to `hdu = fits.PrimaryHDU(da, he)` like in the other cases, to create a new HDU from the already loaded data.

A better way, which according to your comment I think you might have found, is to refactor your code so that instead of passing `fix_fitshead` a filename, pass it an already open `HDUList` object and use it like:

```py
with fits.open(filename) as hdul:
    maxvalue1, spec1, d1, he1, hdu_gray, coord1 = fix_fitshead(hdul)
    ...
```

and don't close the file until you're actually done using it.  This is a more flexible approach in general because it also allows you to use your code on FITS files that weren't directly opened from files on disk (e.g. for writing tests).